# docker-compose Error "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up`, I am getting following error.

> ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Here is my compose file content:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: here is my compose file contents:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Dockerfile` in same dir

   Make sure file named `Dockerfile` is kept in the same directory.
2. `Dockerfile` is in different folder.

   If you are keeping it in some other place, use `context`

```
build:
  context: ./dir
```

3. My `Dockerfile` name is different.

   If you wish to keep `Dockerfile` name different, then use

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
```

Comment: It worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The "build ." directive is looking for the default Dockerfile in your current directory but it cannot find it. If you are just trying to run redis you shouldn't need to build from a Dockerfile.